# Can’t change the region from “US” to “EMEA” ( java)

Tags: java, autodesk-forge

I’m using the library "forge java sdk" and I made the necessary configurations to change the region but in  the manifest usually display “US” .
You can find below some configurations :

[Configuration Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tCwc.png)

[Configuration Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdnNx.png)

The region still displaying “US” :

[Manifest Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu6ZR.png)

How can i fix that ?

Comment: Please try to write as much as possible your code in your question (using code blocks) instead of picture, it's much more easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, **DataManagement** and **ModelDerivative** APIs can use regions independently.

Adam Nagy explains it in this article : [DataManagement and ModelDerivative regions](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/data-management-and-model-derivative-regions).
So I think your bucket is in **EMEA** but your derivatives are still in **US**, so you should delete the old manifest and translate again your file with **EMEA** destination.

Also you can use [OSS Manager](https://oss-manager.autodesk.io/) or [Forge Visual Studio Code](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-visual-studio-code) to help you understand in which regions are your buckets and derivatives.

Comment: Alex is correct. The regions are handled independently between the two services. With the DM service you can configure where the _files_ are stored, and with the MD service you can configure where the _conversion outputs_ are stored.